# XML schema: how to allow one particular element anywhere, openContent?

Tags: xml, xsd

I have a `xml` file that is basically the data of an article. I want to write a `xml schema` to validate that file. In the xml article's file, I have used a few tags in the middle of text, for instance:

```
<p>The dog is <em>brown</em><p>
```

I use that `em` tag elsewhere as well, inside other type of elements, so the problem isn't just to allow it inside `p`.

**My question:** how do I allow it to be used inside any elements of my schema? My research gave me those topics:

[How to allow an XML element to appear anywhere via XSD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43391912/how-to-allow-an-xml-element-to-appear-anywhere-via-xsd)

[XSD: Allow elements from different namespace anywhere in a sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25178259/xsd-allow-elements-from-different-namespace-anywhere-in-a-sequence)

I did not really understand those answers (I am a beginner), but it seems `openContent` might be the solution I am looking for.

Minimal Working Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc>
    <foo>text <bar /> anything</foo>
    <tag>text <bar /> </tag>
</doc>
```

Schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="subclass">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                 <xs:element name="foo">
                 </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="tag">
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

My real document involves some nested `sequence` and `choice`, and other documents I create will be different, so I am looking for a general solution.

**Optional question:** if the solution does not involve `openContent`, can someone explain me how it works as well? Search results were strangely lacking in example and explanations (for beginners), unlike everything I looked up.

Comment: You cite two useful Q/A on the topic, but you don't actually try to use `xs:openContent` in your XSD, so we can't really say where you're going wrong.  Note also that `xs:openContent` requires an XSD **1.1** processor.

Comment: I'm a beginner, I don't understand how to use xs:openContent after looking it up, which I mentionned. However I found out the answer to my question was that it's not possible.

Should I delete the question?

Comment: I'd recommend instead that you post a self-answer that explains how your desired effect isn't possible.  Someone might be able to point out something you missed, or your answer may help future readers.